# Save as layer script not working

Tags: arcpy, layers, error-000732

I've created script in Python for ArcGIS to save shapefile as layer file... the code throws an error:

> ERROR 000732: Input Layer: Dataset D:\core i 5 data\symon assignment\Swat\clipped\buffer.shp does not exist or is not supported

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env 


env.workspace = "D:/core i 5 data/symon assignment/Swat/clipped"
buf= "D:\core i 5 data\symon assignment\Swat\clipped\buffer.shp"
ou2= "D:\core i 5 data\symon assignment\Swat\clipped\layer1.lyr"
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(buf, ou2, "ABSOLUTE")
```

Comment: Not an expert in arcpy but I am pretty sure the paths cannot contain spaces and backspaces are escape signs so they need to be doubled to be taken literally. e.g. "D:\\file\\path\\layer1.lyr".

Answer (score 2):

*Save to Layer File* saves a Layer (in memory, layer from disk, or layer from ArcMap) to a layer (.lyr) file.  It won't work directly on a feature class or shapefile.  You need to first use *Make Feature Layer*.  See [Save to Layer File](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/save-to-layer-file.htm) and [Make Feature Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) on ArcGIS Desktop Help.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env 
env.workspace = r"D:/core i 5 data/symon assignment/Swat/clipped"
buf= r"D:\core i 5 data\symon assignment\Swat\clipped\buffer.shp"
ou2= r"D:\core i 5 data\symon assignment\Swat\clipped\layer1.lyr"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(buf, 'buf_layer')

arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management('buf_layer', ou2, "ABSOLUTE")
```

Also, as mentioned in @Kersten's comment above, you need to be careful with back-slash in path names.  Either reverse them using a forward-slash `/`, double back-slash `\\`, or prefix the string with an `r`.